# Formatting custom field values in email template

Tags: email, email-template

Is it possible to re-format custom field values in a mail merge HTML template in Salesforce? Like to remove a dollar sign, or the cents in a dollar amount?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While it's not officially documented, I believe you can use many [Visualforce functions](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_variables_functions.htm) in email templates. You just have to manually write the function syntax.

For example, the following plain text email template will produce the output shown in the preview below.

```
{!Contact.FirstName}
{!LOWER(Contact.FirstName)}
{!UPPER(Contact.FirstName)}
```

[image: Contact Name email template preview]

Comment: Oh hey, cool. So we can use like `Math.round()` to get rid of decimals? Stripping dollar signs would be tougher I'd imagine, though. Or converting dollar amounts to cents.

Comment: `Math.round()` is an Apex method, not a Visualforce function. Unfortunately I've only seen the ability to use [Visualforce functions](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_variables_functions.htm), not Apex methods. As for stripping dollar signs you may have to create a formula field that simply displays the numeric value of the currency field, and use that formula field in your email template.

Comment: FYI, using `round` works just fine.

Answer (score 0):

Whell, the real answer is NO, it is not possible for CUSTOM fields, it do is just for STANDARD fields.

Comment: Do you have a reference for this claim?